# Drawing TTF text in Slick2D at large sizes causes distortion

Tags: lwjgl

Note: I am using Scala rather than Java but that should not make a difference.

I recently started using LWJGL and am currently trying to draw 2D strings using the TrueTypeFont Slick class, however when I draw a string using `font.drawString(x, y, text, Color.white)` at sizes larger than 48, the text gets distorted. Certain letters in the text become lines, and as I increase the size it becomes more extreme. Below is a comparison of font sizes 48 and 72 being drawn:

[image: Comparison of font size 48 and 72]
My code for creating the font is as follows:

```
val inputStream = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("assets/font/" + file)
val font = new TrueTypeFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, inputStream).deriveFont(size.toFloat), true)
```

I have tried this with both built in fonts (Arial and Times New Roman) and custom fonts like the one above, Augustus and they all have the same problem. How can I render these fonts correctly at larger sizes?